# How can i modify error occurred in c# form design?

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, form-designer

[How to solve this problem (form design )in c#?][image: 1]

Comment: Look in the Form1.Designer.cs file and there should be an error ... specifically line 35.

Comment: Please add the image as part of the question, or better yet - write is as text.

Answer (score 0):

You can click on the blue text:`DBMS 1 Form1.Designer.cs` and after opening Form1 Designer, delete the line (Line:35) which has an error.
This is gonna solve it.